# delete button on each row that echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

every time user insert information and click add button, new data will store to database and echo into this table

table

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="right">
        <input  type="image" value="image"  src="images/btn_add.gif" onclick="action_1()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="title_all_u">Family Member Summary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM family_child WHERE LAS_login_id = ($emp_id)";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Family Type</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </td>           
</tr>
```

and this is insert query

```
if ( $action ==3 ) {
   $spouse_type = $_POST['spouse_type'];
   $spouse_name = $_POST['spouse_name'];

   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO family_spouse (LAS_login_id, spouse_type, spouse_name)  VALUES ('$LAS_login_id', '".strtoupper($spouse_type)."','".strtoupper($spouse_name)."')";
```

this 2 code is working for insert into database and echo in the page.
How can I add delete button below `echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_name'] . "</td>";` for each row that I echo so user can delete the wrong row in the display table.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_name'] . " <a href='page.php&action=delete&id=family_name_id'>Delete</a></td>
```

Then in your page get (if action == delete) > execute your query to delete the row where the ID is the id of the family child name table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM family_child WHERE LAS_login_id = ($emp_id)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Family Type</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>";     

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['family_child_type'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['family_child_name'] . "</td>
    <td>
        <a href='../path/process.php?action=delete&id=".$row['family_child_id']."'>
        DELETE RECORD
        </a>    
    </td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

on process page check action = delete and write query for delete there
family_child_id = ur primary key of table change according to ur table details

**EDIT**

*PROCESS PAGE:*

```
if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
{
    $sql3="DELETE FROM family_child WHERE LAS_login_id =".$_GET["LAS_login_id"]; 
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) 
    {
        header("location:dashboard.php?tab=1");
    }
}
```

Comment: @afifi: look this is ur list page where u displaying list of family..but u will need another page for writing "delete" query..give proper path to that delete record link with action n ID and check on that page by "GET" method and GET['id'] too..and write ur query for delete that perticular record

Comment: this what I do - echo  "<td> <a href='process.php?action=delete&LAS_login_id=".$row['LAS_login_id']."'>DELETE</a></td>"; delete query - if ($action == delete){ $sql3="DELETE * FROM family_child WHERE LAS_login_id = ($emp_id)";
mysql_query($sql3);
header("location:dashboard.php?tab=1"); } it not working for delete.

Comment: LAS_login_id = ($emp_id) is primary key

Comment: I think the query is fine, the problem is here echo  "<td> <a href='process.php?action=delete&LAS_login_id=".$row['LAS_login_id']."'> what is mean by 'action=delete&id'?

Comment: is query given by me executing properly? we r travelling to page process with action n id so on Process page we will come to know wat action is to be perform and on which id we have to perform it..after clicking on DELETE is ur page is linking to process page?

Comment: no.. seem like button DELETE is not working. When I click DELETE, it go to location:dashboard.php which is the main page it should stay at the tab=1 right because we put header("location:dashboard.php?tab=1")

Comment: just give comment to //header and echo $query3; and check whether its working good or not

Comment: if my explanation is sounds poor to u then u can refer : http://www.freezecoders.com/2012/11/add-list-edit-delete-record-in-database-using-php.html

Answer (score 0):

this coding working perfectly. i tried in my pc and posted this code here. it will insert the delete button automatically when u insert the new record. and then if u click delete button it will delete the row details in mysql db..

```
 <body>
    <?
     echo "<tr>
            <td>";
               // your database connection
               // select database
                    $query = ("SELECT * FROM family_child");
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                    echo "<table border=1>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Family Type</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Delete Record</th>
                            </tr>";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_type'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['family_child_name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><form method=post>
                        <input name=id type=hidden value='".$row['family_child_name']."';>
                        <input type=submit name=submit value=Delete>
                        </form></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    echo "</table>";

            echo "</td>           
        </tr>";

       // delete record
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM family_child WHERE family_child_name ='$id'");
    if(!$sql)
    {
        echo ("Could not delete rows" .mysql_error());
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I try this coding, it working but I need to click the delete button 2 times. Then it will delete the row.

Comment: i checked now. it will delete the row when you click that button once. but after that you should reload the page. try like this click the delete button once and then reload the page or go and check the row in mysql db.

Comment: you can use some ajax, javascript or jquery coding for that. when u click the delete button after that it will reload the page automatically. so, find the code for that one...

Comment: did you tried that how to reload the page after click the delete button once?

Comment: I got the solution by refer this http://www.freezecoders.com/2012/11/add-list-edit-delete-record-in-database-using-php.html. thx for helping